# Why is take-while returning empty sequence?

Tags: clojure

What is the rule behind the following behavior:

```
user=> (take-while #(> 10 %) [2 9 4 12 3 99])
(2 9 4)
user=> (take-while #(> % 10) [2 9 4 12 3 99])
()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pretty big difference between "Is 10 bigger than this number?" and "Is this number bigger than 10?". Those are, respectively, the two predicates you have written, and so of course `take-while` behaves differently when given each predicate.

Comment: why the second call does not return (12 99)?

Comment: Why should it? `take-while` is not `filter`

Answer (score 1):

Because take-while stops at the first false

(take-while #(> % 10) [2 9 4 12 3 99])

so the very first check is false it then stops and gives you an empty list. This isnt really made clear in https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/take-while
but its implied
for example take

(take-while #(> % 10) [ 11 15 2 9 4 12 3 99])

will output

(11 15)